Power BI - The total of the columns is not adding up
Im having a problem with Power BI where i put the values in a table but in the total it doesnt show the sum of all the items.
Thats how it's showing in the total of the table:
enter image description here
I tried to adjust with two formulas but it didn't work and it continues to only show the maximum value that was reached :(
first formula:
enter image description here
second:
enter image description here
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Your grand total is taking the aggregation from your Measure. As you are calculating Max for different HostName, it's taking the Max from all HostName in the Total.

yes, i want to fix this issue

Can you please try a Measure like-
measure=
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(your_table_name[HostName]),
    your MAX calculation here,
    your TOTAL calculation here
)


Nice to hear that it worked :)
